# Updating a while loop lists without an i in the statement

Tags: r

I have the following while loop. It applies the following function `possible_collectPageData` over a list of URLs in `failed_to_collect`. The function, `possible_collectPageData` uses `purrr`'s possibly in the following way `possible_collectPageData = possibly(.f = collectPageData, otherwise = "Error")`. So, it returns an `Error` if the function `collectPageData` does not work. I want to go back over this and try to re-collect the data - which is where the `while` loop comes in.

My while loop:

```
while(length(failed_to_collect) > 0){
  listingsData <- failed_to_collect %>%
    map(., ~ map(., ~possible_collectPageData(.x)))

  listingsDataFlat <- listingsData %>% 
    flatten() %>% 
    set_names(failed_to_collect %>% flatten())
  
  failed_to_collect = listingsDataFlat %>% 
    keep(is.character)
}
```

So, the `while` loop will keep running as long as `purrr`'s `possibly` function returns a character error. When the list `failed_to_collect` is 0, then there are no more errors and the `while` loop can stop.

My problem and question is currently the `while` loop updates and overwrite the `listingsData` and `listingsDataFlat` lists. How can I store each iteration as a new list in `listingsData` and append `listingsDataFlat`? Usually, I would have an `i` in the `while` loop and I could use something like `listingsData[[i]]` but in this `while` loop I don't have an `i`.

Comment: You can use `append()` to add the new element to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Would `append()` work for you in this case? Here is a small example

```r
list1 <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
list2 <- list(d = 4)
appended_list <- append(list1, list2)
print(appended_list)
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] 4
```

You could also use `c()`, e.g.

```r
main_list = list()
for (i in 1:5) {
  df = data.frame(x = rnorm(10))
  main_list = c(main_list, df) # Using c() to add to the list
}

str(main_list)
#> List of 5
#>  $ x: num [1:10] 0.958 -1.667 -0.351 -0.312 0.337 ...
#>  $ x: num [1:10] -1.34361 0.00997 -1.4295 -1.37781 2.06532 ...
#>  $ x: num [1:10] -0.0134 -0.3598 -0.7885 0.3675 0.6408 ...
#>  $ x: num [1:10] 0.333 0.214 -0.071 -0.808 2.051 ...
#>  $ x: num [1:10] -0.603 2.6 -1.597 0.164 -0.776 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>